# How to read GSM device from USB port using PHP Script ?

Tags: php, usb, gsm

I have a USB GSM device which I use for Internet connection as well as for Sending SMS through the software provided by the device itself. I would like to know if is it possible to read this device from USB port using PHP server side script ? 
If it is possible, how we can do it & process some actions on it like Send SMS or receive SMS ?

Currently I am using Wamp on my Windows Machine. I would also like to do this on Linux machine too but that is in the very later stage so that is not part of this question at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe with sockets... but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several libraries and tutorials about how to control serial ports with PHP.

Example: https://gist.github.com/51342

Article about this http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=8658A

An article about exactly what you need is [here](http://gonzalo123.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/howto-sendread-smss-using-a-gsm-modem-at-commands-and-php/) (thanks to Mathew Hall)

Comment: For specific commands, see [this post](http://gonzalo123.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/howto-sendread-smss-using-a-gsm-modem-at-commands-and-php/). It provides the code to do exactly what's required, assuming the GSM device you're using uses a COM port (which is highly likely).